# Orbital motion (Mechanics)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, soft-question, resource-recommendations, celestial-mechanics

I am a student in Mechanical department and I took today a lesson with a title of *Orbital motion.* I need a good mechanics reference that discusses this topic.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations

will have everything you need

Comment: I also suggest downloading KSP (google it) and doing a Mun transfer. It is a really good (and fun) way get an intuitive understanding of orbital mechanics.